# isFinishing() is false although application is being destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-activity

According to the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()):

> `public boolean isFinishing ()`
>
> Added in API level 1 Check to see whether this activity is in the
>   process of finishing, either because you called finish() on it or
>   someone else has requested that it finished. **This is often used in
>   onPause() to determine whether the activity is simply pausing or
>   completely finishing**.

But isFinishing() does not work as excepted. Here's the output I'm getting from my app:

> D/com.example.operator.app.MainActivity: onPause() [13513] **isFinishing
>   false**  D/com.example.infra.providers.operator.ExampleProvider: pause()
>   D/com.example.infra.messaging.MessageHandler: stop() 
>   D/com.example.infra.messaging.MessageHandler$1: onDisconnectEvent() 
>   D/com.example.operator.app.MainActivity: onSaveInstanceState() 
>   D/com.example.operator.app.MainActivity: onStop() [13513] isFinishing
>   false  D/com.example.operator.app.screens.MainStackView:
>   onDestroyView()  D/com.example.operator.app.MainActivity: **onDestory()**

so `isFinishing()` returns FALSE although the application IS being destroyed. This is wrong and does not reflect what the API says.

What am I missing?

Comment: Activity class source needed

Comment: Your understanding of [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) is wrong. Activities that are finished are gone from the task stack: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html (often naviation backwards) - when it's saving instance state then because it's coming back later.

Comment: isFinishing() will only be called if the activity has been finished using finish() method I think.

Answer (score 1):

You call isFinishing to early if you call it in onDestroy method it will return true.